# Hibernate 4.1.1 logging with log4j(1.2.17) and sl4fj(1.7.2) under GlassFish Server

Tags: hibernate, glassfish, log4j, slf4j

Dudes, I was using hibernate 3.5 with log4j and slf4. And it was working, logging and binding parameter values. So I updated the hibernate for 4.1.1 version, and after this the log4 doesn't log any information about hibernate(And doesn't show the SQL parameter values). I know the new version use the jboss logging, but I've tried to remove and did not work. I am using GlassFish 3.1.1.2(build5). In my libs i have:

```
-commons-logging
-slf4j-log4j
-log4j(1.2.17)
-slf4j-api(1.7.2)
```

Follow my log4j.properties and hibernate.cfg

hibernate.cfg

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
```

log4.properties

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\teste.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=trace
```

So, its works for other things as you can see my teste.log :

```
13:52:36,692  INFO AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory:76 - Initializing Tiles2     application context. . .
13:52:36,707  WARN ChainedTilesApplicationContextFactory:117 - Cannot find    TilesContextFactory class   org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesApplicationContextFactory
13:52:36,707  INFO AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory:95 - Finished initializing Tiles2 application context.
13:52:36,708  WARN ChainedTilesApplicationContextFactory:117 - Cannot find TilesContextFactory class org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesApplicationContextFactory
13:52:36,770  WARN TilesContainerFactory:365 - DEPRECATION WARNING! You are using parameter-based initialization, that is no longer supported! Please see docs:  http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/configuration.html
13:52:36,771  INFO TilesContainerFactory:372 - Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
13:52:36,774  WARN ChainedTilesApplicationContextFactory:117 - Cannot find TilesContextFactory class org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesApplicationContextFactory
13:52:36,780  INFO ChainedTilesRequestContextFactory:105 - Cannot find TilesRequestContextFactory class org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory, skipping support for the managed platform
13:52:36,836  WARN BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO:209 - Unable to find configured definition '/WEB-INF/tiles.xml'
13:52:36,907  INFO TilesContainerFactory:382 - Tiles2 container initialized
13:52:36,909  INFO TilesAccess:113 - Publishing TilesContext for context: org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesApplicationContext
```

But, the hibernate showing the informations in server stdout as follows. I dont know what the hibernate is using for show it, if i remove the jboss logging, it keep showing

```
Informações: Hibernate: 
select
    this_.cobs_id as cobs1_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_attributes as cobs2_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_description as cobs3_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_name as cobs4_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_position as cobs5_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_sequence as cobs6_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_status as cobs7_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_template as cobs8_5_0_,
    this_.cobs_cosi_id as cobs9_5_0_ 
from
    core.core_blocks this_ 
where
    this_.cobs_cosi_id=? 
    and not exists (
        select
            1 
        from
            core.core_groups_blocks 
        where
            this_.cobs_id=cogb_cobs_id
    ) 
order by
    this_.cobs_sequence asc
Informações: Hibernate:
```

Checking my server stdout i found this:

```
Informações: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Informações: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
```

Probably hibernate is using other log for register the informations, but  i cant find it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is caused by GlassFish 3.1.2.2, i installed the glassfish 3.1.2 and it fixed the problem